# How to prepare an app for Enterprise In-House Distribution in Xcode 3.2.5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, distribution, in-house-distribution

We have purchased Enterprise Program account and by the link

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/DistributinganApp/DistributinganApp.html

I came to know that we can distribute our application to our employees without submission to AppStore.

With help of procedure given in the links

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeArchive.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010402-CH6

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDialog.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010402-CH1-SW1

I was trying to create Archive

through **Product > Archive** as given in link but could not open the window to Archive the app. I am using Xcode 3.2.5?

I could not Find Scheme window .... even by click on project ... upper bar and every here I could not open the one given in Third link. Did not see the given Menu to open the desired screen.

Please tell me How can I open this to proceed.

Comment: "I was trying to create Archive" :Have you chosen ios Device from the scheme available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Solution

I updated it to `Xcode 4.2` and it showed all the desired options.